# MySql error code: 1290 secure_file_priv

Tags: mysql, csv

This question has been asked before and I researched most of the answers, but still no fix.

In MySQL workbench 6.3 CE, I type: load data infile 'C:\Users\User1\Desktop\cm07JAN2014bhav.csv'
into table stockmovements fields terminated by ',' ignore 1 lines;

I then get the secure-file-priv error.

One of the previous answers here in stackoverflow says to find the directory where I can store the file by typing: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv";

I did and get: 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\'

However, after I go into my C Drive there is no "Program Data" folder. Just a "Program Files" folder.

So I cannot find the correct folder path in which to place the csv file so the error message stops.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

try to create the folder 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\Uploads\' or change the setting of `secure_file_priv` and restart MySQL

Comment: I did try to create the "Program Data" folder but it said that it already exists and if I wanted to overwrite it?!  lol   I looked all over the C drive and no such folder exists.

Comment: @Kam it's a hidden folder. You have to go to enable your computer to show hidden folders.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Hidden Items` to show `ProgramData` folder. Have a read: https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/14201/windows-show-hidden-files